# How to sort map by field in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to sort the below object list by distance field. I'm having no success

here is the structure:

`[{"id"=>13, "distance"=>"6612.9"},{"id"=>2, "distance"=>"512.9"},{"id"=>, "distance"=>"343.9"}]`

here is the map

`itemmap = items.map { |item| item.attributes.merge(distance: get_item_distance(item,[params[:latitude], params[:longitude]]).try(:round, 1) }`

Then for sorting I tried the below method but non worked

`itemmap.sort_by(&:distance)`

`itemmap.sort_by { |k, v| v[:distance] }`

`itemmap.map {|item| item.distance }`

`itemmap.sort_by {|item| item.distance}`

Comment: Is "the structure" `items` or `itemmap` or something else? What does the "map" line do and how is it relevant to the sorting?

Comment: @Stefan map its to merge more fields into the object

Comment: So how does the `itemmap` look like that you want to sort?

Comment: @Stefan i want the result to be [{"id"=>13, "distance"=>"343.9"},{"id"=>2, "distance"=>"512.9"},{"id"=>, "distance"=>"6612.9"}]

Comment: The structure you show at the beginning is `itemmap`?

Comment: @Stefan that's the output

Comment: But then, how does `itemmap` look like? Please show the array that you want to sort.

Comment: @Stefan Probably I confused you, when I print using puts "---itemmap---#{itemmap}" I get this [{"id"=>13, "distance"=>"6612.9"},{"id"=>2, "distance"=>"512.9"},{"id"=>, "distance"=>"343.9"}]

Comment: It's indeed confusing. When I asked if the structure in your question is `itemmap` you said _"that's the output"_. When I asked how `itemmap` looks like, you showed the _exact_ structure from your question, including the missing id value for the last element (`"id"=>`). Can you please clarify: what is the structure in your question and what is `itemmap`? Or are they the same?

Answer (score 2):

You are accessing the keys as symbols but they are not. Try the following

```
itemmap = [
  {"id"=>13, "distance"=>"6612.9"},
  {"id"=>2, "distance"=>"512.9"},
  {"id"=>4, "distance"=>"343.9"}
]

itemmap.sort_by { |item| item['distance'].to_f }
#=> [{"id"=>4, "distance"=>"343.9"},
#    {"id"=>2, "distance"=>"512.9"},
#    {"id"=>13, "distance"=>"6612.9"}]
```

Comment: Nice catch totally missed that.

Comment: it's still not sorting the map by distance field

Comment: Then your structure should be different. If `itemmap = [{"id"=>13, "distance"=>"6612.9"},{"id"=>2, "distance"=>"512.9"},{"id"=>4, "distance"=>"343.9"}]` then `itemmap.sort_by { |item| item['distance'].to_f }` sorts it without any problems.

Comment: @AmerBearat note that `sort_by` _returns_ a sorted version of the array, it doesn't change the existing one. To sort the array in-place (i.e. _change_ it), you need `sort_by!` (with a `!`)

Comment: @Christos-AngelosVasilopoulos does it matter if the distance is distance=>7471.7 not "distance"=>"7471.7"

Comment: No, it should work for both assuming you use `to_f`. What do you mean it doesn't work? Do you try to access `itemmap` or the return is not sorted?